# Where to get OpenAl32.Dll that would be capable of running from folder with your app not from system32?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, openal

So I created an app. Usualy its enough to put dlls like ffmpeg ones in folder with it for further app distribution during project creation steps but this OpenAL32.DLL just does not want to work for me like that. So where to get redistributable OpenAL32.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://climpxwss01.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx) is pretty much all you'll ever need/find. Most apps that use openAL, use the installed version. Are you sure you're using the right bitness DLL (32-bit vs 64-bit) and that the missing DLL is the cause of the failure?

Comment: [Dependancy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is your friend.  Nay... your SAVIOR!